# How to convert rows of a database query to a XML file?

Tags: xml, database, delphi, delphi-xe2

I am developing a Delphi application that needs to pick up the rows from a period of work and convert them to a single XML file in order to upload to a 3rd party web-service.

Is there any component or library available to do that? If not, what is the best approach of code to build that DB2XML conversor?

I noticed that most XML questions are about how to convert it to another type of data.

Note: the database will be MySQL or Firebird.

Comment: The code to do this is so trivial, why would you want to use a library? Just roll your own code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`TDataSetProvider`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.Provider.TDataSetProvider) component to fill a [`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) with the TDataSet contents and then use the [`SaveToFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.SaveToFile) method to create the xml file.

Try this sample

```
procedure DataSetToXML(DataSet  : TDataSet; const FileName:string);
var
 LProvider : TDataSetProvider;
 LClient   : TClientDataSet;
begin
   LProvider:=TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
   try
     LProvider.DataSet:=DataSet;
     LClient:=TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
     try
       DataSet.DisableControls;
       try
        if not DataSet.Active then
          DataSet.Active:=True;
        LClient.SetProvider(LProvider);
        LClient.Active:=True;
        LClient.SaveToFile(FileName, dfXMLUTF8);
       finally
         DataSet.EnableControls;
       end;
     finally
       LClient.Free;
     end;
   finally
     LProvider.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: very good. then anything that I should put after, just open the file and insert more data...

Comment: +1, now I'm wondering about the meaning of [`TXMLTransformClient`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xmlxform.TXMLTransformClient) and related (maybe some old school remains ?).

Comment: XMLTransportClient has been around a lot less time than ClientDataSet (which was available in the higher SKUs in D3, IIRC), and made more widely available with D5. XMLTransportClient I believe was added for SOAP/WSDL support much later (I don't think SOAP existed at the time D3 was released).

Answer (score 0):

You could put your table in a TClientDataSet, and then export as XML using the XMLData property.